# Add a name to a specific position in a list

Tags: python, list

How would i make my code add a name to a position (there can only be 10 names in the list) in a list that the user has asked for like this:

```
print (names)
[,,,Bob,,,,,,]

#in my code
names = [] 
name=input('what name would you like to enter?') Bob
pos=input(what position in the list would you like to add to(1-10)?')
```

what would i do after this statement

Comment: you need to first learn how to a) slice a list, and then b) append multiple lists together. Plenty of information on both of those topics already on SO.

Comment: Literally any Python tutorial will show you how to set the item at a specified list index. Note that `[,,,Bob,,,,,,]` isn't really valid, but something like `[None, None, 'Bob', None]` would be.

Comment: `names.insert(pos, Bob)` or `names[pos] = Bob`. But take @jonrsharpe's advice and read a decent tutorial. It'll be able to help better than we could.

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to reference an index in a list, that index has to exist. So, initialize the list:

```
names=[None]*10
```

Then, collect your input:

```
name=input('what name would you like to enter?')
pos=input('what position in the list would you like to add to(1-10)?')
```

Since `pos` will be collected as a `str` object you have to convert it to numeric and subtract one since you are indexing starting with 1 and Python starts indexing at 0.

```
names[int(pos)-1]=name
```